# How can I check if something has written in consol input?

Tags: java

How can I check if something has written in console input? if isn't code will go on but if I will write than something new happens? Is it possible?

```
Scanner k2sk;
k2sk = new Scanner(System.in);
k2sk.nextLine();
```

but code waits until I write something

Comment: k2sk = new Scanner(System.in); and k2sk.nextLine() but code waits until i write something

Comment: @user2610533 Add that to the body of the question.

Comment: So are you asking how to get input without blocking your program execution? @user2610533

Comment: have you tried using another thread ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wait for the user input, and at the same time you don't wish to wait for it,  simply assign that duty to another `Thread`.

Here I have done a short example, hope it will be useful:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestInput {

    public static void main(String[] aa)
    {
         new Thread(new T1()).start();
         System.out.println("MOVED FURTHER");
    }

    public static class T1 implements Runnable
    {

        public void run() {

            Scanner k2sk;
            k2sk = new Scanner(System.in);
            k2sk.nextLine();
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've provided, your program will block at `k2sk.nextLine();` until something appears in the console. While you technically have it correct, that means your program, unless multi-threaded, will hang forever, or until terminated.

One way around this is to make your program multi-threaded, but that may be beyond the scope of the program.

Another solution is to try using the actual Console class. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html) should provide some insight to that, but this would only work if your program revolves around interacting with the user, such as prompting the user for information in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep your thread running after reading the input, I would recommend you dedicating an separated thread to read the input asynchronously:
[How to asynchronously read stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260942/how-to-asynchronously-read-stdin)