# NodsJS Interface with Terminal Process

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, terminal

I am trying to build a WebUI for a Minecraft server. The goal here is to pass the output of the server jar file to the website, while also being able to send commands to it.

Searching Google yields wildly different results with everyone using completely different approaches with everyone using different libraries and specifically crafted tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815734/how-to-call-java-program-from-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

The possible duplicate provides hints, but here is another take

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const path = require("path");

/**
 * Creates a spawner for running a Java application with the ability to terminate the process.
 * @param {string} jarPath - The full path to the Java jar file to be executed. This parameter is used to set the working directory to the jar file's location.
 * @param {string[]} args - An array of command-line arguments to pass to the executable, including the jar option and any additional parameters.
 * @returns {{ run: () => Promise<{outputLines: string[], errorLines: string[]}>, kill: () => boolean }} An object with two methods: `run`, 
 * which executes the Java application and returns a promise that resolves with the process's output and error lines, 
 * and `kill`, which attempts to terminate the running process and returns a boolean indicating success.
 */
const javaSpawner = (jarPath, args = []) => {
  const jarDirectory = path.dirname(jarPath);
  const commandArgs = [...args, "-jar", path.basename(jarPath)];
  /** @type {import("child_process").ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams} */
  let child;
  let stdout = "";
  let stderr = "";

  return {
    run: () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        child = spawn("java", commandArgs, { cwd: jarDirectory });
        stdout = '';
        stderr = '';
        child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
          stdout += data;
        });
        child.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
          stderr += data;
        });
        child.on("close", (code) => {
          if (code === 0) {
            resolve({
              outputLines: stdout.trim().split("\n"),
              errorLines: stderr.trim().split("\n"),
            });
          } else {
            reject(new Error(`Process exited with code ${code}\n${stderr}`));
          }
        });
      });
    },
    kill: () => {
      if (child) {
        return child.kill();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
  };
};

const minecraft = javaSpawner("/some/minecraft/launcher.jar");
minecraft
  .run()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("Output:", result.outputLines);
    console.log("Errors:", result.errorLines);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Execution error:", error);
  });
console.log("now just waiting..");
```

Comment: Thanks, i decided to just use rcon for the minecraft server now, but this will definitely be useful in the future.